# Excel formula to javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel, excel-formula

What will be the equivalent of this excel formula in javascript?

```
=MAX(MIN(EndDate1,EndDate2)-MAX(StartDate1,StartDate2)+1,0)
```

is this even close?

```
Math.Max(Math.Min(EndDate2,EndDate1)-Math.Max(StartDate2,StartDate1)+1,0)
```

What I have tried..

```
var StartDate1 = new Date(2016,12,30); 
var EndDate1 = new Date(2017,10,30); 
var QueryStartDate = new Date (2017, 01,30) 
var QueryEndDate = new Date (2017, 03,30)

Math.Max(Math.Min(ProjectEndDate,QueryEndDate)-Math.Max(ProjectStartDate,QueryStartDate)+1,0)
```

Comment: Well, the second one won't compile since your `StartDateN` and `EndDateN` variables are undefined. Can you include more code?

Comment: Test it with the same inputs and see if it produces the same outputs. You don't need us for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = Math.max(Math.min(EndDate2,EndDate1) - Math.max(StartDate2,StartDate1)+1, 0)
```

This is assuming EndDate* and StartDateN are Date objects.

Comment: Can you do Math.max/min on Date objects though?

Comment: Date object is Integer value representing the number of milliseconds since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC. So yes